# MVC / ViewModel - Trouble with Best Practices in ASP.Net Core 3.1+

Tags: c#, json, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm relatively new to web development in my current role and we have an MVC SPA type application I'm developing with my team.  I can't really share any code directly as it's all the property of my company, so generally:

We're currently working to make a wizard that will collect several points of data and combine it all into the backend's SQL Stored Procs for inserting into tables.  To start we've built a viewmodel that injects in and displays the possible options for various fields / drop downs.  As choices are made in the drop downs it draws in new layers of the wizard.

To keep track of everything selected, I feel like our current strategy might be suboptimal - or more complex than needed.

When the View is interacted with, we're serializing the @Model into json, pushing it into the controller along with any data gathered from the user, de-serializing it into the ViewModel type, and sending it back in to the new partial view - storing any modifications from that action.

This keeps track of the changes as the user works through the wizard and allows us to redraw the primary div/page space to get new information as the context of what we're asking for changes.

I've seen websites do this with Forms or other things like modal pop ups, but as this is a multi step conditional wizard I chose against using that pathway as the views quickly became a mess of conditional razor checks and in page updates.

I know enough to know I'm not sure what best practices are in web development and I'm finding it difficult to extrapolate from various tutorials around the web into the complexity of this particular project.

I can give a generified example of code below, but hopefully the explanation above will trigger someone's brain to help short cut me to a cleaner way to do this.

```
public class XController : Controller
{
    ...
    
    public XController(XRepository xRepository, IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory, Input input)
    {
        _xRepository = xRepository;
        _viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;
        _input = input;
    }

    public IActionResult XIndex()
    {
        return PartialView();  //Draws an add/edit/delete set of buttons to begin the wizard.  Assume the Add button is clicked leading to the next method.
    }

   public IActionResult DisplayAddJob()      
    {
        //get list of task and connection types so user can select
        _taskTypes = _xRepository.GetTaskTypes().ToList();
        _connectionTypes = _xRepository.GetConnectionTypes().ToList();
        _queryTypes = _xRepository.GetQueryTypes().ToList();
        
        //build and return viewmodel so u can bind it to AddjobIndex dropdowns
        XViewModel xvm = _viewModelFactory.Build(User.Identity, _taskTypes, _connectionTypes,_queryTypes, "Miscellaneous", _input.Test);=
        
        return PartialView(xvm);  //The initial view model creation / draw happens here
    }
    
    [ActionName("JobQueryWithPriorData")]
    public IActionResult JobQuery(string vConnection, string vmJson)
    {
        xConnection vc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<xConnection>();
        xViewModel xvm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<xViewModel>(vmJson);

        xvm.SelectedConnectionId = (int)vc.ConnectionId; //we equip the view model with data that changed in the page interaction

        return PartialView("~/Views/Miscellaneous/X/JobQuery.cshtml", xvm); //redraw the view in the main content pane with the updates.
    }
    
    ... 
    
}
```

This pattern exists all across the controller.  An example of the .cshtml code @razor / javascript calls into the Controller are as follows:

Razor:

```html
<td class="td-main-table" valign="middle">
    <button type="button" class="y" onclick="SelectButtonClicked('@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ConnectionList.Where(x=>x.ConnectionId == ct.ConnectionId))','@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)')">
    </button>
</td>
```

Javascript:

```js
function SelectButtonClicked(vConnection, viewmodeljson) 
 {
    var functionalUrl = '/X/QueryToTableWithPriorData'

    $.ajax({
        url: functionalUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            vConnection:vConnection,
            vmJson:viewmodeljson
        },
        success:
            function (response) {
                $('#displayDataPartialView').html(response);
            }
    });
}
```

This methodology is working. We're slowly, over the life of the wizard, able to grab the users selections and keep track of them.  I'm just curious if there is a better way to do this, as I'm certain if there is I'm not aware of where to hunt for it.  I believe in the old days people would just store stuff in ViewData objects, but I didn't really start web dev until .net core 2.1.

My team and I have full creative control over this application, it's internal and something I built from the ground up specifically for our team to put internal tools into, it's fairly lightweight currently and I'm willing to modify it to have a better foundation going forward.

- Would it be better to store the user selections in a table tied to the users session and just recall the data at the end of the wizard on submit?
- Are forms more flexible than I think they are?
- Should I use modal windows instead of redrawing the page every time as a step through this?

*Edit:*

After a few days of research, while I'm not sure I have the best practices by any stretch, I do believe what we're doing is adequate.  I've learned more about client vs server-side rendering and I believe my post came from not quite understanding the two well enough.

I believe the functionality I was expecting was "client-side" functionality from a very server side framework: the ability to step through a wizard's various forms without losing the data as the client goes through.  This can be achieved with javascript/angular/react/blazor manipulating the view without going back to the server with a post/get.

In the world where I'm using minimal javascript, the strategy I'm using to turn the model into json in order to attach more data to it on the server side and resend it to the client for further modification SEEMS appropriate.

I still am interested to see if anyone has a best practice, so I'll leave the question open for a bit longer to see if anyone has anything.  It's possible I should add a more client side layer to the solution as currently my thought was to try and maximize how much I leveraged the C# portion of web development.  It seems like that might be my overall issue here.

Additionally, I spent some time looking into ViewComponents at a the suggestion of a commenter, Xinran.  They are neat and do perform similarly to the PartialView methodology I'm using.  I like how they work, but they produce the same exact scenario.  They are mostly server-side tools, and I still, in the end, run into exactly the scenario that makes me wonder if this is the best way to handle a wizard with multiple steps that evolves off the user's previous choices.

Comment: You need to write your question more clearly.

Comment: Succinctly: 

We're using partial views to separate different portions of the data we need to set up a job.  We're controlling those partial views all through one controller since the business need is a singular combination of these smaller pieces through the partial view.  This means we need to pass data back from each partial view's user interactions.

Is the best method for handling this serializing and deserializing the ViewModel back and forth as you add new user inputs to it?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you want to pass date from view, Why don't you use `View Component`?

Comment: There is no reason other than I'm new at web dev and hadn't considered that (or even knew about them!). I assumed based on my own browsing that partial views would be the best strategy for an SPA.  I will look into these and see if I can swap them in for partial views or if that gives me new problems.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment Xinran, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are wlecome. If you just want to display some view, `Partial View` is a good choice, But if you want to pass the data, `View Component` is a better choice, Because you can add logic in it. Here is a link about [View Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: As a follow-up here, after looking at it, I'm still not sure how it would help resolve my problem.

We need to step through about 4 screens worth of information gathering.  To do that right now: I draw a partial view, send that data back to the controller AND send the viewmodel back. This preserves whatever is in the ViewModel and adds the user input across the remaining steps.

I'm not sure that ViewComponents will solve the issue of using the Controller to step through, because we lose the ViewModel data every time an Action is called and it recreates the Controller in the backend. 1/2

Comment: Does ViewComponent work because I could write it such that I could put all the 4 steps in one page and hide 3 of them.  As you finish one you can hide it and unhide the 2nd, then 3rd, then 4th, and at the end you can go to the controller one time with all 4 ViewComponents values as arguments?

This stops the Controller from losing the ViewModel data because it doesn't destroy itself every time since it only gets called at the tail end with all data.  Is that what you think would be cleaner?

2/2